# MySQL workbench won't send database to localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I am trying to send my Database from Mysql Workbench version(10.4.11) to my localhost/phpmyadmin ,(on windows 10 using mysql and xampp) I havw mysql and apache ON ,but I get this error when I try to Forward engineer my DB ,

Any suggestions ,questions or an another easier way to do it would be appreciated 
Basically what I want to have is these tables connected and be able to run a simple query that will for example create a Driver and require his ID,Name etc.

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tblDriver_tblPolicy1`
 FOREIGN KEY (`tblPolicy_idPolicy`)
 ' at line 17
SQL Code:
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `InsuraceCO`.`tblDriver`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `InsuraceCO`.`tblDriver` (
      `idDriver` INT NOT NULL,
      `FirstName` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
      `LastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Age` INT NULL,
      `Street address` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
      `AddressPostcode` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `Phone Number` INT NULL,
      `LicenseStatus` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      `DateLicenced` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `LicenceNumber` INT NOT NULL,
      `tblPolicy_idPolicy` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idDriver`, `tblPolicy_idPolicy`),
      INDEX `fk_tblDriver_tblPolicy1_idx` (`tblPolicy_idPolicy` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_tblDriver_tblPolicy1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`tblPolicy_idPolicy`)
        REFERENCES `InsuraceCO`.`tblPolicy` (`idPolicy`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

And here is my code

````
    -- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

    SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
    SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
     SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE,




 SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Schema InsuraceCO
    -- -----------------------------------------------------

    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Schema InsuraceCO
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `InsuraceCO` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
    USE `InsuraceCO` ;

    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `InsuraceCO`.`tblPolicy`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `InsuraceCO`.`tblPolicy` (
     `idPolicy` INT NOT NULL,
     `PolicyEffectiveDate` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
     `PolicyExpirationDate` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
     `TotalCost` INT NULL,
  `PlayerID` INT NULL,
  `LastUpdate` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tblPolicycol` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPolicy`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `InsuraceCO`.`tblDriver`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `InsuraceCO`.`tblDriver` (
  `idDriver` INT NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Age` INT NULL,
  `Street address` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `AddressPostcode` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Phone Number` INT NULL,
  `LicenseStatus` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `DateLicenced` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `LicenceNumber` INT NOT NULL,
  `tblPolicy_idPolicy` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDriver`, `tblPolicy_idPolicy`),
  INDEX `fk_tblDriver_tblPolicy1_idx` (`tblPolicy_idPolicy` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tblDriver_tblPolicy1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tblPolicy_idPolicy`)
    REFERENCES `InsuraceCO`.`tblPolicy` (`idPolicy`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `InsuraceCO`.`tblVehicle`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `InsuraceCO`.`tblVehicle` (
  `idVehicle` INT NOT NULL,
  `VehiclePlateNumber` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `VehicleBrand` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `VehicleModel` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `RegistrationYear` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `RegistrationNumber` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `EngineNumber` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `EngineSize` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `idPolicy` INT NOT NULL,
  `tblPolicy_idPolicy` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idVehicle`, `tblPolicy_idPolicy`),
  INDEX `fk_tblVehicle_tblPolicy1_idx` (`tblPolicy_idPolicy` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tblVehicle_tblPolicy1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tblPolicy_idPolicy`)
    REFERENCES `InsuraceCO`.`tblPolicy` (`idPolicy`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `InsuraceCO`.`tblViolationCodes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `InsuraceCO`.`tblViolationCodes` (
  `idViolationCodes` INT NOT NULL,
  `ViolationDescription` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idViolationCodes`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `InsuraceCO`.`tblDriver_tblVehicle`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `InsuraceCO`.`tblDriver_tblVehicle` (
  `tblDriver_intDriverID` INT NOT NULL,
  `tblVehicle_intVehicle` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tblDriver_intDriverID`, `tblVehicle_intVehicle`),
  INDEX `fk_tblDriver_has_tblVehicle_tblVehicle1_idx` (`tblVehicle_intVehicle` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_tblDriver_has_tblVehicle_tblDriver_idx` (`tblDriver_intDriverID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tblDriver_has_tblVehicle_tblDriver`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tblDriver_intDriverID`)
    REFERENCES `InsuraceCO`.`tblDriver` (`idDriver`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tblDriver_has_tblVehicle_tblVehicle1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tblVehicle_intVehicle`)
    REFERENCES `InsuraceCO`.`tblVehicle` (`idVehicle`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `InsuraceCO`.`tblDriver_tblViolationCodes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `InsuraceCO`.`tblDriver_tblViolationCodes` (
  `tblDriver_intDriverID` INT NOT NULL,
  `tblViolationCodes_idtblViolationCodes` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tblDriver_intDriverID`, `tblViolationCodes_idtblViolationCodes`),
  INDEX `fk_tblDriver_has_tblViolationCodes_tblViolationCodes1_idx` (`tblViolationCodes_idtblViolationCodes` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_tblDriver_has_tblViolationCodes_tblDriver1_idx` (`tblDriver_intDriverID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tblDriver_has_tblViolationCodes_tblDriver1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tblDriver_intDriverID`)
    REFERENCES `InsuraceCO`.`tblDriver` (`idDriver`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tblDriver_has_tblViolationCodes_tblViolationCodes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tblViolationCodes_idtblViolationCodes`)
    REFERENCES `InsuraceCO`.`tblViolationCodes` (`idViolationCodes`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
   SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;```
````

Comment: I don't think MariaDB supports the `VISIBLE` and `INVISIBLE` options for indexes.

Comment: I concur with @Barmar,... the problem is the keyword `VISIBLE` ...  that's where I would start with debugging, removing that keyword.

Comment: That is it ! Thank you both !!!